# Simple calculus question in kinematics with time or distance as independant variable

Tags: calculus, kinematics

It is easy to solve the basic kinamatics equation:

$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = v(t)$

$\frac{dv(t)}{dt} = a(t)$

$\frac{da(t)}{dt} = j$

and get the discrete version:

$x(t+1) = x(t) + v(t)t + \frac{1}{2}a(t)t^2 + \frac{1}{6}jt^3$

$v(t+1) = v(t) + a(t)t + \frac{1}{2}jt^2$

$a(t+1) = a(t) + jt$

So how about the case using $x$ as independent variable? What is the discrete version of solution for constant jerk?

$\frac{dv(x)}{dx} = \frac{a(x)}{v(x)}$

$\frac{da(x)}{dx} = \frac{j}{v(x)}$

$\frac{dt(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{v(x)}$

Comment: $\frac{dx}{dx}$ is always $1$ because you are taking the derivative of a variable with respect to itself, so your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{dx}{dx}$?  I think things would be more clear if you did not suppress the inputs to your functions.  For example, instead of writing $\frac{dx}{dt} = v$, you could write "$x'(t) = v(t)$ for all $t \geq 0$".

Comment: Sorry everyone, I make a mistake. Please check it now.

Comment: It should be $\frac 16jt^3$

Comment: Correct it now. Sorry. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Those solutions you presented on top are correct only for constant jerk ($j$). In any case, can't the second set of equations be immediately transformed to the first using the chain rule? They look equivalent to me, it's just that the first set are more clearly parametrised by time (which makes better physical sense).

Comment: Yes, it is only for constant jerk. The second set equations is using $x$ as indepentant variable. As I am trying to use the discrete version of second set equations, I am not sure how to solve it. I have tried, but it seems to solve a cubic equation and cannot find a easy answer.

Answer (score 0):

These are the same equations written differently, with the same solution.  For example $\frac {dv}{dx}=\frac {dv}{dt}\frac {dt}{dx}=a \cdot \frac 1v$ using the chain rule and the derivative of an inverse.  Since the equations are the same, the solution is the same as well under the same assumption of constant jerk.

Comment: Hello, I refined the question just now. I know that it is only chain rule tranformation, but I still cannot get the discrete version of solution. It seems that the problem is the cubic equation.

Comment: Your problem is not changing the set of equations, it is changing the independent variable from $t$ to $x$.  You can solve the $t$ equation for $t(x)$ and plug that into the others but you have a mess.  What is the advantage?

Comment: The reason why I need $x$ as independent variable is related to speciafic problem. It is more convenient to control the multiple vehicles from one place to another. Jerk is control variable, so I need to get the  discrete system dynamic function, but it is a little more messy than using $t$ as independant variable. Can you provide me any suggestions?

Comment: All the more reason to use time.   All the vehicles agree on it.  What happens if one stops?  Then its $x$ is not a good independent variable.

Comment: For the controlled vehicle, the purpose is to pass the intersection without stop, then stop can be avoid. $x$ is more convient to describe the problem that all the vehicles pass the intersection at terminal step. If using $t$, then only the first arrive at the intersection.